# UIWebview didn't work in iphone6, but work on iphone6 simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I'm developing and app and part of it is to use the `UIWebView` to show something.

```
-(void)loadRequestFromString:(NSString*)urlString
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

it works in the iPhone 6 simulator but didn't work on iPhone 6. And it showed up the webpage in simulator, but it's blank in iphone6. I'm not sure what's the problem. Can anyone help me with that? Is there any security setttings for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work?"

Comment: So it shows nothing inside iphone6. In Simulator the corresponding webpage shows up, but in iphone6 it's just blank

Comment: Can you access the same URL in Safari on your iPhone 6?

Comment: Yes, I can. And I tested Google and Yahoo. None of them works. And this code also works on iphone5. I'm not sure whether there's some security settings for iphone6 that I missed.

Comment: Perhaps web page is cached with some blank page. Not that uncommon if you are building the web backend at the same time as the app.